# Countable additivity of measure with given "good" marginals

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be **Polish** spaces, $X=X_1\times\dots\times X_n$. For each $X_i$ we fix some Borel probability measure $\mu_i$. If $\pi$ is a regular bounded finitely additive Borel measure on $X$ with given marginals $(\operatorname{Pr}_i)_\#\pi=\mu_i$ for $i=1,...,n$, is it possible to say something about $\sigma$-additivity of $\pi$?

Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: Theorem 1 of this paper http://stat.columbia.edu/~porbanz/reports/porbanz_bochner.pdf give a partial response

Comment: If $X$ is compact, regularity alone implies that it is countably additive.